# Logs full of "page not found" entries for various *.js.map files

Tags: log-messages

Our Drupal 9 site is full of "page not found" warnings in the Drupal logs. All entries end in *.js.map (all map files). I cannot figure out where the warnings are coming from (what system is trying to find non-existent map files?) or how to resolve.

See screenshot for examples of not-found files.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that someone browsed the site with developer tools enabled, which tried to load debugging files that do not exist.

`.map` files, known as "sourcemap" files, are used by [web browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) for debugging CSS and JavaScript by allowing minified and aggregated CSS and JavaScript to appear in their original source code forms.

`.map` files are not necessary for the normal operation of a web site. If `.map` files are missing, it is because a preprocessor did not create them, or in some cases, a vendor did not provide them.

There is an [open issue in Drupal core](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3227125) to create these.